# Opening a file from specified folder inside dir. where .exe is

Tags: c++, file, location, directory

I need help with opening a file in a folder called "Edit Data" that is in the same folder as the .exe I am making.  I am not sure of how the opening of files from folders is handled in c++. 
Example of what I want.

....\Program\Edit Data   <- I want to open a file from this folder and edit it

....\Program\program.exe  <- Location of .exe

I need to do this because I have multiple files inside this folder that the user can edit.
I first tried to use a folder for Mod.dat called Mod but I was unsuccessful.

Half of my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main ()
{


string filename;//file that will be changed
//string path = "Mod/Mod.dat";//Path of Mod.dat that I could not get to work
//string file = path + "Mod.dat";//this was for opinging Mod.dat from folder call Mod, didnt work
long size;
char* memblock;
cout << " Enter a file to be modded by Mod.dat  ";
cin >> filename;

ofstream infile ( filename ,std::ofstream::binary | ofstream::in);//the file that will be opened and changed)
//"filename: I want to open it from a folder called Edit Data

ifstream modFile ( "Mod.dat" , ifstream::binary);// (mod.dat is the file that i get the first 1840 hex values from)

if (!infile){
    cout << " Couldn't open " << filename << endl;
}

if (!modFile){
    cout << " Couldn't open " << modFile << endl;
}
```

I don't know if this is important but I use Visual Studios and my program opens "infile" and edits it.
I also want to open about 1000 files from the Edit Data folder and edit them with the mod.dat.
( Edit: As of now, I mainly just need to know how to read a single file from a folder.)
Also is there a method where I can make a text document with the file name and location that the ofstream reads when I add it to the inside of a loop?

What the files would look like:
         ....\Program\Edit Data\12a.dat
         ....\Program\Edit Data\m9i3.dat
         ....\Program\Edit Data\2020.dat

Answer (score 1):

You can use dirent.h to obtain an array of all the files inside the Edit Data folder, afterwards you just open the *.dat ones.

Or you could open a file in X place with a list of the files you want to edit and their filepath, keep in mind that the path either is complete ("C:\Program Files\Edit Data") or variable such as ("..\Edit Data").

Comment: Would this "C:\Program Files\Edit Data" allow me to access the file if I was to write is as:  "C:\Program Files\Edit Data\(file to be edited).dat"?

Comment: Problem is you either know the name of the file beforehand or give it through an argument taken from the user (cin or getline). If you don't do this you have to search for the file instead using a filesystem library, that's what dirent.h is for (or you could use fseek), you could also use boost filesystem. The access to the file depends on you program's permissions, if you run it as administrator you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Ok I just got the dirent.h and im going to try that out. Right now I am many focusing on opening one file, I can even seem to do that.

Comment: Its seams I cant get the dirent.h to work, Im not sure how it works either.